# How can I add a VirtualBox machine to the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, virtualbox, launcher

VirtualBox allows me to put a shortcut icon for a virtual machine to the Desktop:

[image]

I tried to drag it to the Unity launcher but cannot place it there.

Is there any way to add a desktop shortcut icon of a virtual machine to the Unity launcher?

Comment: One *single* box, or add it as a shortcut to (e.g.) the virtualbox launcher?

Comment: I apologise for my duplicate. In fact, I could resolve it myself. After trying it a couple of more times, I was able to place the single virtual machine onto the launcher: http://i.imgur.com/rbp7qEZ.png

Comment: Don't worry, it is not a shame to post a dupe :)